# I need to generate random numbers but each number must be different from the other

Tags: python, random, numbers, unique

I got a function in another file, to recall that function i use:

```
app.put_number(row, column, number)
```

which is basically generating a matrix, but in the first column, for each row I need a random number from 1 to 20, and each number must be unique, I tried using random.randrange().
For example:

```
app.put_number(0, 0, random.randrange(1,21))
app.put_number(1, 0, random.randrange(1,21))
```

But sometimes it generates the same number and I need that each one of them to be different.

Plus I cant mess with the file with the actual function, I can only use if, else, while, for and app.put_number(row, column, number)

Comment: This is asked once per week here. Search a bit!

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you tagged your question with a specific language you would like to complete this task in.

Conceptually, however; you need to check the populated array every time a new number is generated to ensure that you are not inserting a number already in the array. If you want to get fancy you could even have an array of numbers and randomly choose the index of the array you are putting the numbers into, effectively "shuffling" them together.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Random.sample(). It returns unique numbers in a range
As per doc below "To choose a sample from a range of integers, use a range() object as an argument. This is especially fast and space efficient for sampling from a large population: sample(range(10000000), k=60)."

https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to keep the generated numbers in a list and then calling the random number generator until it gives a number that is not present in your list of already generated numbers.